Is this Chernoff-like bound for supermartingales known?
[Note: This post was migrated from mathoverflow.net, as it received no answer there.]
Does anybody know a reference (in the literature) for the following theorem, or a theorem in a similar form?

Theorem 1. Let $(x_t)_{t=1}^\infty$ and $(y_t)_{t=1}^\infty$ be two random sequences in $[0,1]$ such that for all $t\ge 0$ $$ E\left[x_t - y_t \mid (x_s)_{s=1}^{t-1}, (y_s)_{s=1}^{t-1}\right] \le 0. $$
Then for any $\epsilon\in (0,1)$, the probability of the event $$ \textstyle (\exists t \ge 0)~~ \sum_{s=1}^t x_s/(1+\epsilon) - \sum_{s=1}^t y_s/(1-\epsilon) \,\ge\, \epsilon \mu$$
is at most $\exp(-\epsilon^2\mu)$.

I previously mentioned (and gave a proof of) this theorem in this answer.  Now I'm wondering if it or something similar is already published somewhere.
A "similar" theorem should similarly bound the probability that a large deviation occurs at any time $t$, not just a single predetermined time $t$.
(Or, if that is not known, then a fallback would be a theorem that bounds the probability that a large deviation occurs for a given (random) stopping time $T$.)
Thanks for reading!
